# Selecting multiple attributes, greater and less than

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, select-by-attribute

I am trying to select by attributes from a polygon shapefile. I need to select areas with a temperature greater than 10 oC and lower than 15oC using gridcode but I can't seem to work out the correct formula.

Can anyone help?

The process so far has been Geoprocessing, selection by attributes,

```
"GRIDCODE"=  >10, <15
```

to which an error window comes up stating invalid SQL statement.

I am using ArcMap 10.3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need to use the following instead:

```
"GRIDCODE" >= 10 AND "GRIDCODE" < 15
```

You need to switch the `=>` operators and specify again the attribute field for the second term (i.e. `< 15`).

Comment: @TheoBlundell please mark this answer as correct if it helped you out. It may help someone else as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
"GRIDCODE" IN ('10', '11', '12', '13', '14')
```

If the data type for the field is String rather than a numeric type.  Otherwise use the method described by Joseph.